# Working with spaces in id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to get the class name of the id with spaces but struggle to get it correct .  Here is part of my code

```
<div onclick="javascript:Myfunction(value1.value,'AA BB',value2.value,'ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890AA BB"></div>
 <div onclick="javascript:Myfunction(value1.value,'CC',value2.value,'ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890CC"></div>


<script>

function Myfunction(value1, value2)
{
 var ValId='1234567890';
 var a =  ValId+ '' + value1;
       // not working showing syntax error error 
        alert($('div[id='+a+']').attr('class')); 

        // working 
                alert($("div[id='1234567890AA BB']").attr('class')); 
  }
</script>
```

Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters - so, don't expect it to work

Comment: It is not working since **value1.value** is not defined

Comment: @JaromandaX alert($("div[id='1234567890AA BB']").attr('class'));  this is working fine

Comment: [**HTML 5**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)  is more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.

Comment: @user2181397 only sample coe i have posted the value of value1.value is AA BB(for eg )

Answer (score 0):

It's not preferable to use id with space.

But I would like to help you with following code, that will give the id of that div based on the click only.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"   integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="clasname" id="1234567890AA BB">Test2</div>
<div class="clasname" id="1234567890CC">Test1</div>

<script>
$('.clasname').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **not correct to take spaces in your id's**, instead take `underscore(_)` for your id's.

**ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").**

`Eg:  1234567890_AA_BB,1234567890_AA_BB etc`

Also, you are sending four parameters to the function, but taking only two of them in the function definition.Take only two parameters.

```
<div onclick="javascript:Myfunction('AA_BB','ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890AA_BB"></div>
<div onclick="javascript:Myfunction('CC','ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890CC"></div>
```

You should send only two parameters, this may work for you.

```
<div onclick="javascript:Myfunction('AA_BB','ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890_AA_BB"></div>
<div onclick="javascript:Myfunction(value1.value,'CC',value2.value,'ddd')" class="clasname" id="1234567890CC"></div>

<script>
function Myfunction(value1, value2)
 {
    var ValId='1234567890';
    var a =  ValId+'_'+value1; // Gives you '1234567890_AA_BB'
    alert($("div[id='+a+']").attr('class')); 
 }
</script>
```